# Recursive Insert via binary search

Tags: java, sorting, insert

I have a sorted array and want to recursively find a position for inserting an element. E.g. an array 2,4,5,6,7,8,12,35 with an insertion value of 3 and the algorithm should return the index of the position where the 3 has to be inserted (index 1).
The following code works sometimes, and other times it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Eventually my brain feels like jelly and I ask for your help. This is the code:

```
private static int insertRec(int[] a, int e, int l, int r) {
    int mid = l + r / 2;
    if (l == r || a[mid] == e) return mid;
    if (e > a[mid]) insertRec(a, e, mid + 1, r);
    if (e < a[mid]) insertRec(a, e, l, mid - 1);
    return -1;

}
```

Edit with assumed working code:

```
private static int insertRec(int[] a, int e, int l, int r) {
    int mid = (l + r) / 2;
    if (l == r || a[mid] == e) return mid;
    else if (e > a[mid]) return insertRec(a, e, mid + 1, r);
    else if (e < a[mid]) return insertRec(a, e, l, mid - 1);
    return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int mid = l + r / 2;
```

It should be

```
int mid = (l + r) / 2;
```

**EDIT**: moreover, you can check the description of the STL algorithm [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) which makes exactly what you want, as I understand. A implementation based on this would be like:

```
int lb(int a[], int last, int val) { // array, len of the array, element to insert
  int it, count, step;
  int first = 0;
  count = (last-first);
  while (count > 0) {
    it = first;
    step = count/2;
    it += step;
    if (a[it] < val) {
      first = ++it;
      count -= step+1;
    } else
      count = step;
  }
  return first;
}
```

**EDIT2**: your code has a few mistakes to work properly, among them:

- in the second line you cannot check if `a[mid] == e` because the element you want to insert, may not exist in the array. This will cause to return -1 in several cases.
- the infinite loop arises from the way of computing `mid` and later assigning `mid+1` or `mid-1`.
- because the element you want to insert may be equal to some elements in the array, you will be returning incorrectly, since you compare for both `e > a[mid]` and `e < a[mid]`.

I advice you to take a look at this fantastic [post](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/9901) about binary search. In any case, here's the algorithm trying to follow the more possible your style and using the info of the post. Hope it helps.

```
private static int insertRec(int[] a, int e, int l, int r) {
    int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
    if (l == r) return l;
    else if (a[mid] < e) return insertRec(a, e, mid+1, r);
    else return insertRec(a, e, l, mid);
}
```

Comment: You are totally right about this (did I mention my jelly brain?)
But that is not the entire solution to my problem. Take the array 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7 and try to insert a 3 with my algorithm. It produces -1

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu check my edit. I didn't check your algorithm completely, just the obvious part.

Comment: I thank you for your fast answer. The problem is, that your lb algorithm does not use binary search but performs a linear iteration.

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu it uses a binary search, but it is implemented iteratively. You can easily convert it to a recursive version. I will check your code now.

Comment: I have to check your code later. I am too brainwashed at the moment to properly understand what it is doing. I edited my question with a suggestion. The method now works a bit better but there are still cases, where an infinite loop occurs or a wrong insertion index is returned (0, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9 suggests an insertion an pos 0 and not at pos 1)

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu I checked your code already. Have a look at the edit. Good luck.