# Recursively inserting an element in a sorted array

Tags: c

So the idea is to insert an element in an already sorted array. For example, if we have an array `arr[]={1,2,3,5,6}` and we insert the element 4 the array automatically becomes `arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6}`.
I managed to write a code that achieves that using loops but I didn't figure it out **recursively**.

This is my failed attempt:

```
void inser(int t[], int n, int x)
{
    if (n==0)
        {
            *t=x;
        }
    else
    {
        inser(*(t+1),n-1,x);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your iterative solution?

Comment: You need to shuffle numbers up the array, and your recursive code doesn't attempt to do that.  You need to rethink how your recursion algorithm works.

Answer (score 0):

There are some logical error, But the main error is, you have to call `inser` like this way

```
inser((t+1),n-1,x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way using 0 as sentinel value. If your numbers are not always greater than 0, then you can set another sentinel value with `memset()`.

If you don't want to use sentinel values, I guess you have to use a linked list. An array is a constant pointer, you can't change its size.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void inser(int t[], int n, int x);

int main() {

    int t[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6};
    int x;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    inser(t, 0, x);

    for(int i = 0; t[i] != 0; i++) {
    
        printf("%d ", t[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void inser(int t[], int n, int x)
{
    if( n < SIZE ) {
    
        int hold;

        if( t[n] != 0 ) {

            if( t[n] > x ) {
    
                hold = t[n];
                t[n] = x;
                x = hold;
            }
    
            inser(t, n+1, x);
        }
        else {
    
            t[n] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26950666/10071237), the following implementation does the job:

```
int lb(int a[], int last, int val) { // array, len of the array, element to insert
  int it, count, step;
  int first = 0;
  count = (last-first);
  while (count > 0) {
    it = first;
    step = count/2;
    it += step;
    if (a[it] < val) {
      first = ++it;
      count -= step+1;
    } else
      count = step;
  }
  return first;
}
```